# Creating a dynamic string in C#

Tags: c#, string, ref

I have string which I create like:

```
string label = Name + " " + Number;
```

where `Name` and `Number` are properties. I want this label string to change whenever the `Name` or `Number` is updated. I tried to use the `ref` keyword but C# tells me that I can't use `ref` for properties. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Why can't you just update the string in your `Name` and `Number` property setters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create it as another property, with only a `get` method:

```
public string Label { get { return Name + " " + Number; }}
```

This way, every time you call the property it will create the return value based on the current values of `Name` and `Number`.

This needs to be defined at a class level though, and `Label` is probably not an appropriate name either.

---

Of course, the question now is, why call it `Label` in the first place?

If you are using this value to set a WinForms style label control, and you want to update that dynamically then you will need a different approach. you could modify your current properties for `Name` and `Number` to do a "little extra work" in the setters.

For example:

```
private string _name
public string Name 
{
    get { return _name; }
    set { _name = value; DoChange(); }
}

private string _number
public string Number 
{
    get { return _number; }
    set { _number = value; DoChange(); }
}

public string Label { get { return Name + " " + Number; }}

private void DoChange()
{
    MyLabel.Text = Label;
}
```

This might be overkill for this question, but just something to think about.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a `Label` property, inside the class that provides `Name` and `Number`, like so:

```
public string Label 
{
    get
    {
        return Name + " " + Number;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even being a *reference type* a `string` behaves like a *value type*, so every time you assign to it something it keeps a new **copy** of the value.

But even if it wouldn't behave like that, this will not resolve your problem, as your `label` value is compositional value, based on other 2 values.

You need to architect your code in a way, that when:

(just an example) one of the properties is changed (`Name` or `Number`), event raised, so label *recomputes* its value.